# Move <tr> with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table on my page like this:

```
 <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>first</td>
        <td><a href="#">first click</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>second</td>
         <td><a href="#">second click</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>third</td>
         <td><a href="#">third click</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr id="change">
         <td colspan="2">
            <button>change</button>
          </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

When I click on of the links, I want the move '#change'  under the clicked link's . For example; when I click on "first click" table changes like this..

```
 <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>first</td>
        <td><a href="#">first click</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr id="change">
         <td colspan="2">
            <button>change</button>
          </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>second</td>
         <td><a href="#">second click</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>third</td>
         <td><a href="#">third click</a></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

How can I do it with JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('table tr td a').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').after($('#change'));
});​
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NQ4tQ/4/)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('td a').click(function(){
    $(this).parents("tr").after($('#change'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6AMnV/

Answer (score 1):

Using *event delegation*, therefore only adding on event listener to the mix rather than several:

```
// Using Event Delegation only adds one event listener
​$("table").on("click", "a", function (event) {
    // Prevent any navigation or jumping to the top of the page
    event.preventDefault();
    // Find the closest <tr>, insert #change after it.
    $(this).closest("tr").after($("#change"));
});​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: +1 for adding a small efficiency to the other answers.  I never think about the delegation listeners.

Answer (score 0):

try this (untested)

```
jQuery('td a').each(function(){
    var j = jQuery(this);
    jTr = j.closest('table').find('#change');
    j.closest('tr').after(jTr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").click( function(){
  var $change = $('#change');
  $('#change').remove();  
  $(this).closest('tr').after($change);
});​
```

Comment: wouldn't this do nothing? as you just deleted it before you put it somewhere?

Comment: `detatch` would be better than `remove`, but neither are really needed since "after" will remove it from the original location and put it in the new one.